# Missing files when try to install a forked package

Tags: react-native, npm

I created a fork from [react-native-calendar](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars). But it doesn't add all files when I try to install it with npm. for example in the calendar folder, there is not any JS and TS file. You can check my forked version [here](https://github.com/alinavaie/react-native-calendars-forked).

Forked Package:

[image: Foeked package]

Original Package:

[image: Original package]

**✅ Solved:**
The package needs to preinstall